# 000000 and 111111 has different size but same css,, how can i get the same size of font

Tags: css, reactjs

```
<Badge display={"flex"} justifyContent={"center"} position={'absolute'} zIndex={2} width="60px" height="16px" right="18px" top="15px" fontFamily={"Roboto"} fontWeight={"700"}  variant='solid'  alignItems={'center'} colorScheme="blue">00:00:00</Badge>

<Badge display={"flex"} justifyContent={"center"} position={'absolute'} zIndex={2} width="60px" height="16px" right="18px" top="15px" fontFamily={"Roboto"} fontWeight={"700"}  variant='solid'  alignItems={'center'} colorScheme="blue">11:11:11</Badge>
```

this two has same css but 11:11:11 is more thinner than 00:00:00 how can i get the same size of two

what should i have to  try?

Comment: Either use a monospace font, or set a fixed width of the `Badge`.

Comment: i set the Badge width and height and  Badge size was set but not the font width

Comment: Of course setting a width for the containing element, does not change how wide individual pieces of text go. You need to either use a monospace font, or at least one that has same-width digits - or you will have to break this into multiple elements, so that you can give each two-digit group a width separately.